# Check where include/library path variables like OpenCV_LIBS point to in unix

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, include-path, library-path

When using some libraries like OpenCV with C/C++, variables like OpenCV_LIBS are used to point the compiler/linker to the relevant directories.

Examples using [cmake](/questions/tagged/cmake):

```
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
target_link_libraries( project_name ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

How can I check where such variables point at? I've tried typing `set` or `printenv` in terminal but it shows only some system variables. Also how can I set/change such variables?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Those variables are determined by [cmake](/questions/tagged/cmake) (see [`OpenCVConfig.cmake`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/cmake/templates/OpenCVConfig.cmake.in) for a more detailed description of [opencv](/questions/tagged/opencv) CMake variables available).

To see those values you can add `message()` calls after the `find_package(OpenCV)` call to your project's `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(OpenCV)

message(STATUS "OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS = ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "OpenCV_LIBS = ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
```

---

Alternatively you can run `find_package` via a CMake command line option.

Here are a few examples (the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` part is optional if CMake is not able to find your libraries installation path automatically):

1. `MODE=COMPILE` giving include directories (e.g. with `MSVC` compiler)

   ```
   $ cmake 
       --find-package 
       -DNAME=OpenCV 
       -DCOMPILER_ID=MSVC -DMSVC_VERSION=1700 
       -DLANGUAGE=CXX 
       -DMODE=COMPILE 
       -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:PATH=/path/to/your/OpenCV/build
   ```
2. `MODE=LINK` giving link libraries (e.g. with `GNU` compiler)

   ```
   $ cmake 
       --find-package 
       -DNAME=OpenCV 
       -DCOMPILER_ID=GNU 
       -DLANGUAGE=CXX 
       -DMODE=LINK 
       -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:PATH=/path/to/your/OpenCV/build
   ```

*Note:* This CMake call will create a `CMakeFiles` sub-directory in your current working directory.

---

**References**

- [Using OpenCV with gcc and CMake](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-last-rst/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html)
- [`CMakeFindPackageMode` CMake module documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakeFindPackageMode.html)