# Is OpenCV installed or not in my Jetson nano? How to build a C++ program with it?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to use opencv with C++ in my jetson nano and I cannot build my C++ program (I remember vaguely that I could in the past)

The thing is if I try to compile the C++ code and it says

```
 fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory  #include
<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

so I do

```
pkg-config --modversion opencv
Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'opencv' found
```

and I do

```
pkg-config opencv --cflags
Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'opencv' found
```

However if I do this:

```
python
Python 2.7.17 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:07:09) 
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux2
```

and then

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'4.1.1'
```

I also have a python program using opencv and it works.

So what am I doing wrong with C++??

EDIT:

I managed to build my program following the directions of the OpenCV docs. (and similar to what I later found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33981618/check-where-include-library-path-variables-like-opencv-libs-point-to-in-unix)

So I basically made a subdirectory where I put a `CMakeLists.txt` as in

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( first )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_executable( first first.cpp )
target_link_libraries( first ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

and then run `cmake .` and then `make`

With that I could build the program.

But I have no idea why I could not build it with gcc and where the openCV is installed.

Comment: Which documentation did u follow? Did u get any error during make?

Comment: I am trying to do https://github.com/JetsonHacksNano/CSI-Camera

Comment: curiously the  python version do work

Comment: This is not the right documentation to follow, why u not use a normal installation guide. You just installed python_opencv libraries not for c++

Comment: Curiously it seems they are installed. I managed to build the program but with cmake. I wonder why I cannot do it manually. (I still don't know where opencv is) (see Edit)