# ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} not set after building OpenCV from source

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I followed this tutorial to build OpenCV:
https://qengineering.eu/install-opencv-on-raspberry-pi.html

It built and installed successfully, but trying to include `opencv2/opencv.hpp` is not working. The file is definitely present in `/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp`.

I know I could just add it as an include directory in the C++ project with the `-I` flag, but I want to understand why it's not working.

The `${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}` is not defined. Is it supposed to be added to `.bashrc` or somewhere else by Make? Did a certain step fail without warning?

Comment: `${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}` is from CMake when  you use `find_package(opencv)` in your CMakeLists.txt that you have for the code you are building.

Comment: please contact the author of the tutorial.

Comment: Here is what I am talking about in my first comment about ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} : [https://stackoverflow.com/a/42658058/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42658058/487892) When configuring your CMakeLists.txt  `${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}` is set if you have a find_package(opencv) and OpenCV was found.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz the tutorial is based on OpenCV build documentation, it just fills in the parts that are missing in the original documentation and adds a few things like swap file resizing that don't affect the outcome of the build process, only its speed.

Comment: @drescherjm is it true in general that OpenCV tutorials simply don't include the information on how to compile the code? In other words, they assume that you either use `find_package` or the `-I` flag to tell the compiler that OpenCV is located at `/usr/local/include`. If that's so, feel free to add that as a reply and I will accept.

Comment: The tutorial you link is about installing opencv on your raspberry, not about how to include it in another project. That's why it doesn't cover this. `find_package` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @drescherjm for pointing me to OpenCV make documentation and @Wutz for confirming:

https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/df5/tutorial_linux_gcc_cmake.html

This has you create CMakeLists.txt, then run `cmake .` to create Makefile, then run `make` to build using the makefile.

That will correctly tell the compiler where OpenCV is using macros for include and lib.

Comment: current docs contain a warning that the article may be out of date. it's identical to the "3.0-last-rst" article: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/df5/tutorial_linux_gcc_cmake.html

Comment: updated link to latest